# Navigation Bar with ul and icons on left and right: icons on the right get pushed down

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-position, navbar

I've done the whole nav bar and everything is perfect but the buttons on the right sand, after the nav bar menu, get pushed down to the next line and messes up the whole nav bar, making it very thick.

I've isolated all the code and I think it looks very clean.

Thats my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8" />
    <title>My about page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wifi">
            <img src="img/wifi.gif" alt="Wi-Fi" />
        </div>
        <div class="opcoes">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Casa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quartos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="flags">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/flag_en.gif" alt="English" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/flag_pt.gif" alt="Português" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my style.css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    overflow: hidden;
}

header{
    text-align: center;
    background: #C07D41;
}

.opcoes li{
    display: inline;
}

.opcoes li:after{
    content:'|';
    padding: 0 8px;
} 

.opcoes li:last-child:after{
    content: none;
}

.wifi{
    float: left;
    padding: 13px 8px;
}

.flags li{
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
```

Any help appreciated, really stuck in it, need icons on left and right and centralized nav bar, is it possible this way I'm doing or am I gonna have to use a table? Really don't know, been on this for hours.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use float left in css on `.opcoes` class and float right on `.flags` class

or make them `display:inline-block;`

Comment: yes that is perfect and i saw it before but that override the aligning of the .opcoes menu in the center of the page . any ideas how to get the navbar items centralized on the page again after doing that?

Comment: add width to the navbar so that the other items fit there

Comment: it's not a fitting problem i think and i've tried that before. the problems is the line break ul does after the .opcoes menu

Comment: to align item u have to use float property of css

Comment: than what is the issue?

Comment: ok but as i need to use float: left to be able to leave the flags on the same line i cant adjust it properly to the center, is that right?

Comment: issue is the two flags are being put on the next line when they should stay in the same line as the nav bar

Comment: it works but i haven't really understood it 100%. my time to study it now. don't really get why that width:50% works.thanks heaps mate

Answer (score 0):

```
.opcoes, .flags ul, .flags li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/YkU6e/